# Char manipulation in gobject

Tags: glib, gobject

I have following string: `"/local/usr/bin/conf.xml"`.
I would like to replace `"conf.xml"` with e.g. `"new_conf.xml"` so that I get `"/local/usr/bin/new_conf.xml"`

Any idea how to do it using gobject?

Thanks!

Comment: if it's always going to be a path, look at g_path_get_dirname and g_strdup_printf.  And be sure to free the memory you're not using anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GFile` for path manipulation:

```
GFile *conf = g_file_new_for_path ("/local/usr/bin/conf.xml");
GFile *parent = g_file_get_parent (conf);
GFile *new_conf = g_file_get_child (parent, "new_conf.xml");
g_object_unref (conf);
g_object_unref (parent);
```